# short Wordpress plugin url with htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very long url for my plugin pages so I want to make it short using htaccess but I'm confused about editing wordpress .htaccess when the plugin activated by rewrite the .htaccess file.

I see there's some rewrite hooks for wordpress but I'm totally don't know how to use them.
Tried a lot of time to use them but no luck.

This is my plugin url:

```
/wp-content/plugins/myplugindir/showpage.php?pagename=$1
```

And that's the rewrite:

```
^mypluginname/(.*)$
```

Full RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^mypluginname/(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/myplugindir/showpage.php?pagename=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: You should create an endpoint: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51444/add-extra-parameters-after-permalink/51450#51450

Comment: You have to edit Wordpress' config, not .htaccess. Wordpress will not recognize the new urls, and thus it will serve 404's.